# How to reset Performance objects in perfmon?

Tags: windows, perfmon

When I launch perfmon and try to add a counter, the displayed performance objects are all numbers. How can I reset these Performance objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem:

- copy C:\WINDOWS\system32\PerfStringBackup.INI from a PC where perfmon works correctly
- cd C:\WINDOWS\system32
- lodctr /R:PerfStringBackup.INI

Comment: Glad you found a solution :) Any idea what corrupted the perfmon strings to begin with?

Comment: So you used lodctr /s:PerfStringBackup.INI on the working machine to generate the file?

Comment: JeffH,
Actually no (may be I should have?). The file was already present.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean my "reset"? What's the behavior you're expecting?

The perfmon "System Monitor" view shows the (near) real time value of the counter. Since these measurements are always being taken there will (almost) always be a number there.

If you want to be able to control the collection of these measurements, you need to create a Counter Log. Additionally, you can use the logman command to manage the log from the command line or a script.

Comment: I mean the performance objects ("Paging File", "Process", ".NET CLR Data", etc.) are all replaced by numbers in the combo "Performance objects"). Hence I'd like to go back to a more "normal" situation